Meaning of "As much as they came to revel in their pathos..." in "The Gate" by Natsume Sōseki
From The Gate (1910) by Natsume Sōseki, translated by William F. Sibley (2013):

In any case, the two of them had come this far without either sitting in a
church pew or passing through a temple gate. At length they had found
peace through that simple blessing of nature: the balm of time. Even as they
continued to suffer pangs of conscience on occasion, these increasingly
seemed to come from somewhere far away, too faint, too weak, and too
disconnected from flesh-and-blood passions to qualify as either terrifying or
excruciating. Finally, then, not having found God or encountered the
Buddha, they focused their faith on each other. Their spirits locked together
in an embrace, they began to form a protective circle around themselves. It
was in this state of isolation that they had managed to find peace. Their
lonely peace was complemented by a certain sweet sense of pathos. As
much as they came to revel in their pathos, they were far enough removed
from the realms of philosophers and poets to harbor any self-conscious need
to proclaim aloud their good fortune in having achieved it. Their experience
was therefore unalloyed in comparison to that of the writers and thinkers
who must strive to describe states of this nature. Such had been the couple’s
inner life up until the seventh day of this New Year, when Sōsuke was
invited to the Sakais’ and heard the news about Yasui.

I do not get the meaning of "self-conscious need" and the whole phrase clearly.
Does the whole sentence mean "As much as they came to revel in their pathos they could not came over their worrying feelings about how people think about them to be able to proclaim aloud their good fortune like something that is written in books of philosophers or poets"

for "came over", do you mean overcome? a self-conscious need can a need that might cause embarassment.

Yes I mean "overcome"

Sōseki is contrasting how the couple experiences their own feelings, with how poets or philosophers would experience or view those feelings.
If a poet or a philosopher feels something out of the realm of ordinary experience, the poet or philosopher has the drive to talk about it: to write a poem reflecting this feeling, or an essay discussing it. This means that such writers are always somewhat self-conscious, or at least self-aware: they regard the feeling from the outside, as it were. Somewhere in their mind there is a faculty that says, I am undergoing this particular emotional state.
The couple here do not have any such drive to externalize what they are feeling so that they can poetize or philosophize about it. So their experience is unalloyed: they feel this "sweet sense of pathos" without simultaneously regarding it and themselves self-consciously. Sōseki says that because poets and philosophers have this self-consciousness, this need to describe their feeling as or to an observer even while they experience it, they cannot lose themselves in the feeling in the way that this couple can do and has done.

The sentence basically says, Sosuke and Oyone are in the state of feeling sweet pathos and at the same time unaware that they are in such a state. The assumption is that Soseki thought that poets/writers would regard such a state as kind of "higher" and feel satisfaction of some sorts about being in such a "superior" state. Sosuke and Oyone were free from that kind of attitude and were pure/innocent in that sense.
The translation

As much as they came to revel in their pathos, they were far enough removed from the realms of philosophers and poets to harbor any self-conscious need to proclaim aloud their good fortune in having achieved it. Their experience was therefore unalloyed in comparison to that of the writers and thinkers who must strive to describe states of this nature.

corresponds in the original to

文芸にも哲学にも縁のない彼らは、この味を舐め尽しながら、自分で自分の状態を得意がって自覚するほどの知識を有たなかったから、同じ境遇にある詩人や文人などよりも、一層純粋であった。

Translating as literally as possible, it means

They (Sosuke and Oyone) didn't read literature or philosophy and, tasting the sweetness to its full, they didn't have enough knowledge1 to be pompously aware2 of their own state. Because of this, they were all the more pure/innocent than poets or writers in the same situation.

1 You may think it refers to something like pedanticity.
2 得意がって自覚する is a bit hard to translate, but it refers to poets etc. regarding feeling sweetness in pathos as something important.
